# Concat digit to variable's and display it

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I want to add a suffix (0) to variable containing a value in Kshell using shell scripting and then display the variable+suffix on screen

For e.g

```
abc.ksh 35 14063
```

What I tried is

```
var=$2
echo " ( value should be $var\0) "
```

OUTPUT should be `140630`

But it is not working for me..What am i missing in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to **delineate variable names to be expanded inside a double-quoted string containing other elements, use `${...}`, i.e.,  enclose the variable name in `{}`**:

```
echo "${var}0"
```

This applies to all Bourne-like (POSIX-compatible) shells, such as `bash`, `zsh`, and `dash`.

Comment: Thanks,getting expected result now but can you tell me what was the problem in my approach

Comment: @user3449519: If you do `echo "$var0"`, then `ksh` won't know that it's only the `var` part is the variable name and instead assume that a variable name `var0` is referenced, given that digits are valid characters in variable names. By enclosing `var` in `{}`, you instruct the shell to only consider the text between `{` and `}` the variable name.